# joining points together in inkspace

Tags: inkscape

Im completely new to inkspace and im struggling to get 2/3 points to join together seemlessley so I can begin filling my image.

So far I have this....

[image]

I just cant figure out the process of joinging the two points together, I have tried breaking the points apart and rejoinging them but then I am left with another point that is not linked in. Any idea?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't join nodes that are part of different closed paths, or open paths to closed paths. It's not possible in vector software, such as Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator. The only thing possible is to line them up by moving them manually. Inkscape has a Snap to Nodes option in the Snapping Controls to help you line them up if required.

Comment: Thanks Billy, I will draw a rectangle over the top and do it that way, Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: That's a nice answer. I upvoted to give you some rep!

Answer (score 2):

As Billy pointed out it is not actually possible, so to get around this issue I first drew the whole head, and then I drew a rectangle over the top for details and lined that up with the arches of the head itself.

[image]

Thanks Billy.